# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}]$ is semi-simple

Tags: ring-theory

Showing that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}]$ is semi-simple.

Then I denote that first $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$ and the second one as $\{e,g\}$.

Then I have that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}]=\{0,e,g,e+g\}=\{0,e\}\oplus \{0,g\}\oplus \{0,e+g\}$

Which is a direct sum of semi-simple rings hence it is semi-simple.

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e+g$ is in the span if the first two summands, so that sum isn't direct ( and Alexander already pointed out that would make too many elements anyway.)

> *Yeah if I just leave the last summand off I think I am ok right?*

No, because $\{0,e\}$ is not an ideal of the ring.

---

Actually, [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) tells us we should not expect this ring to be semisimple.

Since $(\sum g)^2=n(\sum g)$ where n is the order of the group, and $n=0$ In this case because of the characteristic, you can see that here $\sum g$ is a nonzero nilpotent element, and hence lies in the radical.

Comment: So $\{0,e\}$ is not an ideal as $\{0,e\}g\not\subset \{0,e\}$ but $\{0,g\}$ is an ideal right as is $\{0,e+g\}$ so does this choice work?

Comment: Yes, it does. Just convince yourself these are both the field of two elements! @hmmmm

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the pretty trivial question

Comment: {0,g} is not an ideal? e=g*g is in the ideal spanned by it. The question is a little crazy since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,(x-1)^2)$ is clearly not semisimple as it is commutative and has nilpotent elements: $(e+g) = e^2 + eg+ge+g^2 = e +eg+eg+e = 2(e+eg) = 0$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Are you saying that $\{0,g\}$ is an ideal? I am now confused, don't we have $\{0,g\}g=\{0,e\}$ hence this is not an ideal?

Comment: @hmmmm oof , I mixed up some additive and multiplicative notation for the group, and fooled myself into thinking it is semisimple. Of course I shouldn't have expected this when the order of the group isn't a unit I the field. If you don't mind, I'll correct my answer now.

Comment: @JackSchmidt thanks, can't believe I talked myself into that.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, your direct sum decomposition can't really make sense because $\{0, e\} \oplus \{0, g \} \oplus \{0, e+g\}$ formally has $8$ elements, but you've written your ring as only having $4$ elements. Something similar to this should work though.

Comment: oh yeah, oops. Yeah if I just leave the last summand off I think I am ok right?